# I just changed the text editor, so this error has no solution. ---->Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

blade:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

 <td><i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-success mr-3"></i> {{ $post->user->id}}</td>
```

> I just changed the text editor, so this error has no solution. I have
> tried all possible solutions because it is useless

Model User

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Model Post

```
  public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Comment: what does a text editor have to do with anything? ... apparently that `$post` doesn't have a `user`

Comment: Never assume something exists... `$post->user` is returning `null`, so you can't access `id` from it (`null` does not have a property `id`). Add a check for existence before accessing `id`, adjust your initial query, enforce relationship via database logic, etc. This has **nothing** to do with your text editor...

Comment: @TimLewis I have tried all possible solutions and have not worked out

Comment: @lagbox So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `$post` object does not have a `user` model connected to this instance.  It can't get an `id` from null.

To check, dump your `$post` model - make sure there is a `user` attached.  If not, check your `store()` / `update()` methods - are you successfully attaching the `user` to the `$post` model?

Comment: So how does it work with unrelated well even because
I have tried all possible solutions and have not worked out
 I have a relationship with  **Role**  it works fine

Comment: Your relationship on the `$post` model is fine.  It's just that for that particular `$post`, there is no `user` attached.  Make sure your `store()` and `update()` methods are attaching the user to the post.  Review the `attach()` and `sync()` methods in Laravel - are you actually adding the user to the post in the store/update methods?  Look at your tables to see, or dump the `$post` model - if there is no `user` attached, you know that it was not correctly added.